# Hashing a string in a PCL?

Tags: c#, hash, portable-class-library

I have a PCL in which I would like to hash a string. I would like to use it for an image downloader, which needs to store the image to disk. To make the imagename unique for each URL, I thought about hashing the URL to obtain a unique string for each link.

Now my problem is that I can't seem to find any hashing classes in the PCL API. I don't need a fancy one, and I sure as hell don't want to get a NuGet package with 20 hashing algorithms. This needs to be a small PCL and I don't want to include more than I need.

Is there a way I can easily create a string representation (doesn't need to be secure, may even be reversible, it should only have a very low chance of collisions and the string must not have slashes in it, as I want to use it as a filename) of a URL using the API provided in a PCL or by including only one small class?

All I need is a way to turn a string I cannot use as a filename into one I can use as a filename. The only other requirement is that this action gives the same output for each input.

Comment: Why mess with the file name at all? - `originalname, originalname001, originalname002 ...`

Comment: @AlexK. because we are running into issues where the same file appears in multiple folders on the server (a folder called `thumbs` and a folder called `full`). And because of that our application takes the cached (thumb) version, where it should take the new one (full-resolution).

Comment: how about `Guid.NewGuid()` then?

Comment: @slawekwin then the images won't be cached, I can just as well not cache them then. All I need is a way to turn a string I cannot use as a filename into one I can use as a filename. The only other requirement is that this action gives the same output for each input.

Comment: Well, the usual solution to that is to use escaping or some other sanitization method. It really depends on what kind of user you're targeting, but since you're already considering some hash, it's not a big difference. The advantage of this approach is that you will *never* get collisions. Have you considered adding the URL as metadata to the file or something like that?